# I can't write multiline codes in Coffeescript Interactive Mode(REPL)

Tags: coffeescript, multiline, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

When I typed multiline in coffeescript interactive mode, an error occrured.

For example, I want to try the following code:

```
kids =
  brother:
    name: "Max"
    age:  11
  sister:
    name: "Ida"
    age:  9
```

This Error was displayed:

```
coffee> kids = 
Error: In repl, Parse error on line 1: Unexpected 'TERMINATOR'
  at Object.parseError (/usr/lib/coffeescript/parser.js:463:11)
  at Object.parse (/usr/lib/coffeescript/parser.js:533:22)
  at /usr/lib/coffeescript/coffee-script.js:26:22
  at Object.eval (/usr/lib/coffeescript/coffee-script.js:64:17)
  at Interface.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/coffeescript/repl.js:18:26)
  at Interface.emit (events:27:15)
  at Interface._ttyWrite (readline:309:12)
  at Interface.write (readline:147:30)
  at Stream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/coffeescript/repl.js:35:17)
  at Stream.emit (events:27:15)
```

I tried to use '\' as a newline,but the same error was displayed.

```
coffee> kids = \
Error: In repl, Parse error on line 1: Unexpected '\'
  at Object.parseError (/usr/lib/coffeescript/parser.js:463:11)
  at Object.parse (/usr/lib/coffeescript/parser.js:533:22)
  at /usr/lib/coffeescript/coffee-script.js:26:22
  at Object.eval (/usr/lib/coffeescript/coffee-script.js:64:17)
  at Interface.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/coffeescript/repl.js:18:26)
  at Interface.emit (events:27:15)
  at Interface._ttyWrite (readline:309:12)
  at Interface.write (readline:147:30)
  at Stream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/coffeescript/repl.js:35:17)
  at Stream.emit (events:27:15)
```

I can't use multiline, so I can't use indentation.

What should I do?

My environment is the following:

- OS: Ubuntu 10.04 lucid
- coffeescript version 1.0.0
  I installed coffeescript with PPA and apt-get command.

see this url: https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/coffeescript

Comment: I highly recommend installing Node.js separately and then using `npm install -g coffee-script@1.3.1`. That way, you can easily install any version of CoffeeScript that you want and update to new versions as soon as they're available.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I changed the installation using ppa into using npm.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can also switch to multiline mode with **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>**.

Comment: doesn't work...coffee> fill = (container, liquid = "coffee") -> "filling the #{container} with #{liquid}.."
[Function]
coffee> fill "cup"
'filling the cup with coffee..'
------> shit = (container, liquid = "coffee") ->
....... "filling the #{container} with #{liquid}.."
ReferenceError: container is not defined

Comment: I am using node with vscode on Windows and it's terminal eats my ctrl-v and fires the paste from clipboard event.  So I changed the hardcoded 'v' at node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl.js:91:73 to a 'b'

Answer (score 1):

backslash works fine with my coffee 1.2.1... try to upgrade :)